# Creating a Delphi app shortcut with no corresponding menu item

Tags: delphi, menu, shortcut, taction, tmenuitem

I want to have a shortcut key combination (like Ctrl+Alt+D) in my app to invoke a function, but I don't want the shortcut to appear on any menu.  Is it possible to have a shortcut available in your app that is otherwise invisible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the [`OnShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnShortCut) event of the [`TApplicationEvents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents) component to this task

check this code

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.CharCode = Ord('D')) and (HiWord(Msg.KeyData) and KF_ALTDOWN <> 0) and  (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Ctrl+Alt+D Pressed') ;
    Handled := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent.  Works a treat and doesn't involve any action components.

Comment: If you are already using a TActionList for the other actions on the form, just adding another TAction with the required shortcut is more elegant and improves readability.
(as suggested by Giacomo Degli Esposti)

Comment: I'm not using actionlists although I probably should,  It's an app that started life before I knew what they were and I've never been bothered enough to retro-fit them.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's possible. You must add an Object of class TAction to your form.
You can specify a keyboard shortcut for the Taction and then put your code in event OnExecute of the TAction.

Note that you cannot add a Taction directly to your form, you must put a TactionList on your form and then you can add a Taction to your TActionList.